# jQuery Validate PHP Response

Tags: php, jquery, json, validation

My problem is that I want to validate an email address with jquery. Not only the syntax but rather if the email is already registered. There are some tutorials but they are not working!
 At first the Jquery Code:

```
<script id="demo" type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
 // validate signup form on keyup and submit
 var validator = $("form#signupform").validate({
  rules: {
   Vorname: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 3
   },
   Nachname:{
    required: true,
    minlength: 4
   },
   password: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 5
   },
   password_confirm: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    equalTo: "#password"
   },
   Email: {
    required: true,
    email: true,
    type: "POST",
    remote: "remotemail.php"
   },
   dateformat: "required",
  ...
</script>
```

And now the PHP Code:

```
<?php
    include('dbsettings.php');

    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpw); 
    mysql_select_db($dbdb,$conn);

    $auslesen1 = "SELECT Email FROM flo_user"; 
    $auslesen2 = mysql_query($auslesen1,$conn); 
    $registered_email = mysql_fetch_assoc($auslesen2);
    $requested_email  = $_POST['Email'];

    if( in_array($requested_email, $registered_email) ){
        echo "false";
    }
    else{
        echo "true";
    }
?>
```

I tried return TRUE/ return FALSE as well, but this displays "Email is registered" all the time. `json_encode` didn't work either.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: German (and any other non-english) code is ugly. I'm also German btw.

Give your variables meaningful, english names.
"Auslesen" ("read") is not meaningful. For example, instead of $auslesen1 you should use $sql and $result instead of $auslesen2.

Additionally, your code will throw a E_NOTICE if $_POST['Email'] is not present.

Comment: So, basically, what you're saying is that the php code returns the right value but your javascript keeps displaying false, no matter what the php code returns, correct? Have you tried, `depends: function(){//do ajax call}`?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote) the value seems to be passed as a get parameter. Replace $_POST['Email'] with $_GET['Email'] and see if that works for you.

Also [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) doesn't handle multidimensional arrays, which the array is. Maybe a better technique would be to add a WHERE clause to your SQL statement something like

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Email']);
$sql = 'select Email from users where Email = '.$email;
$result = mysql_query($query, $dbconn);
$resultAsArray = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if(count($resultAsArray)==0) {
    echo true;
}
else {
    echo false;
}
```